# External stylesheet in custom element (no Polymer)

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, stylesheet, element

I'm building a custom element. this is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pols-notifier.css">
  <div class="body">
   <button class="close"></button>
   <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
  class PolsNotifier extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
   }

   connectedCallback() {
    const instance = this.currentDocument.querySelector('template').content.cloneNode(true);
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(instance);
   }
  }
  
  window.customElements.define('pols-notifier', PolsNotifier);
 </script>
</html>
```

And the page is:

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="import" href="http://localhost:8080/assets/pols-notifier/pols-notifier.html">
    <body>
  <pols-notifier></pols-notifier>
 </body>
</html>
```

The console show an error when try load the stylesheet. The file of custom element and the stylesheet are in /assets/pols-notifier directory in my project but the navigator is looking /pols-notifier.css.

Why is looking there?

Greeting. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the error message, that is logged?

Comment: It says "GET http:://localhost:8080/pols-notifer.css net::ERR_ABORTED"